# Should one file 1040X to get extra $5 tax refund

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, brokerage, form-1099-div

After I finished my taxed in last week of March, I received a Updated 1099 with only one modification where 199a is modified from zero to $50 or so. Refund is about to come in a week.

Initial values 
Box 1a = 500
Box 1b = 200
(all other boxes empty)

similar question is at [Am I required to amend my tax return if I overpaid my taxes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107968/)

Updated values
Box 1a = 500
Box 1b = 200
Box 5 = $50

---

The effect of this update is about $5 more tax refund. And to get this refund I will spend more in postage. 
So my question is , is it ok to leave the money with IRS or by law I am required to get it fixed.

This question was asked on April 08, 2019 before the [Am I required to amend my tax return if I overpaid my taxes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107968) ( asked on April 18) @joetaxpayer , The marking says

> This question has been **asked before** and already has an answer.

I agree that this question has answer at the referenced location, the part that I disagree is "asked before"

Comment: How do you spend $5 in postage?  A first-class stamp is 55 cents these days - and if you're like me, you probably have half a book of "forever" stamps that you bought 5 years ago in your desk drawer.

Comment: I didn't think shipping physical copies of information was still a thing....

Comment: @jamesqf Certified Mail Fee is $3.50 and if one amends Federal, one also needs to ament State tax return

Comment: @xyious per https://www.irs.gov/faqs/electronic-filing-e-file/amended-returns/amended-returns "You must file Form 1040X on paper and mail it to the IRS"

Comment: Why certified mail, though?  And I tend to forget about you unfortunate folks who live in places with state income taxes :-)

Comment: I thought I had answered this question once before and I had. See  [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107968/am-i-required-to-amend-my-tax-return-if-i-overpaid-my-taxes/108320#108320)  You should not spend one more microsecond worrying about this.

Comment: @Neil Re. "_This question has been asked **before**_" I believe this is slightly unfortunate wording (that probably won't get changed). If two questions ask essentially the same thing (and/or lead to essentially the same answer) then _one_ of them will be closed, pointing to the other. Sometimes deciding which will point at the other will be based on the date of asking, sometimes on which got better answer(s) before someone noticed, and sometimes it might be more or less arbitrary (as I understand it... I don't make the decision!) Don't worry too much either way.

Comment: @TripeHound thanks, I understand

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on the legal position on this as written in the law. However I asked a tax lawyer this question a few years ago (specifically about the case of getting an amended 1099 which only changed the liability slightly, in the tax payer's favor).

They advised me that unless the IRS proactively contacted the tax payer mentioning the correction and offering a refund that it was not necessary to do anything.

They also mentioned several exceptions, if the field had specific information filing requirements, such as effecting form 8938, but this is likely not relevant to you.

Note this is not legal advice and may not apply to your circumstances specifically, and this is not the right stack to get legal advice or ask questions of law.