# how long is it allowed for Brokerages to send updated 1099

Tags: united-states, irs, form-1099, discount-broker, form-1099-div

One brokerage has send me an updated 1099. I am wondering by law how late these Brokerages can send the corrected/updated 1099? I think It is about Feb 20 of the calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/newsletters/2015/nov/heres-how-to-fix-problems-caused-by-late-and-amended-forms-1099.html
**Brokerage firms can amend and issue corrected Forms 1099 at any time**

Comment: I have a question https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107541/should-one-file-1040x-to-get-extra-5-tax-refund if you can answer